# Dual set of the unit ball is part of the unit ball.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, computational-geometry, discrete-geometry

Define **the unit ball centered at the origin** as $B=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d\mid \|x\|\leq 1\}$.

Define **the dual set** of set $X$ as $X^*=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^d\mid\langle x,y \rangle\leq 1\ \forall x\in X\}$.

I'm attempting to prove that for any set $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$ it holds that $C=B$ if and only if $C=C^*$. I've managed to prove the implication from the right to the left by the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

However, I'm having some trouble with the converse implication. In particular, how to prove that $C=B$ implies $C^*\subseteq C$?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow here.  Let $d = 1$, so that $B$ is the interval $[-1, 1]$.  How does $B^*$ contain anything besides the single point $0$?

Comment: @BrianTung For any $x,y \in [-1,1]$, $\langle x,y \rangle = xy \leq 1$. So any $y \in [-1,1]$ belongs to $B^*$.

Comment: @BrianTung If $B=[-1,1]$, then $B^*$ are by definition all solutions $y$ to $xy\leq 1$ where $x\in[-1,1]$. In this particular case, you can take only the boundaries of the interval and obtain two inequalities: $-y\leq 1$ and $y\leq 1$. These will intersect at $B^*=[-1,1]$.

Comment: Sorry, I misread inner product as distance.  Carry on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it. Thanks to @AhmedHussein for the hint.

Take any $y\in B^*$. If $y=0$, then clearly $y\in B$, so assume otherwise. Notice that $\frac{1}{||y||}y\in B$, and thus by the definition of $B^*$ it holds that $\langle\frac{1}{||y||}y, y\rangle\leq 1$.

Extract the coefficient: $\frac{1}{||y||}\langle y, y\rangle\leq 1$.
Multiply both sides by $||y||$: $\langle y, y\rangle\leq ||y||$

We can now substitute $||y||^2=\langle y,y \rangle$ and obtain inequality: $||y||^2\leq ||y||$. This is true only if $||y||\leq 1$. Hence, $y$ belongs to $B$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

For $y \in B^*$, notice that if $y \neq 0$ then $\frac1{\|y\|} y \in B$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I have used it in my answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1584875/145607

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $C=C^*$, you have $<x,x>=\|x\|\leq 1$ since $x\in C,x\in C^*$ thus $C\subset B$. This implies $B^*=B\subset C^*=C$ since it is easily shown that $X\subset Y$ implies $Y^*\subset X^*$. done.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about this theorem.